# Mass reading files and mass inserting in postgres db

Tags: python, postgresql, multithreading, file

I have **2.5M+ html files** in a folder called html/

The file name is like id.html
id is an integer ascending (1, 2, 3, [...])

The files are like a page containing shipping orders.

**I'm looping through each id/file in ascending order, using regex to get the data that i need in html, then i insert into pgsql using id as primary key**

I'm looking for a faster approach.

```py
def extract_html_information(file_path: str) -> dict:
    with open(file_path, 'r') as f:
        # getting info, regex, normalization logic
    return dict_with_all_information

def insert_into_pgsql(id: int, info: dict) -> None:
    query = f"""
    UPDATE order_additional_info
    SET order_status = '{info['order_status']}', tracking_status = '{info['tracking_id']}'
    WHERE id = '{id}';
    """
    # insert logic on db

def main():
    min_id = 1
    max_id = 2523123
    for id in range(min_id, max_id):
        file_path = f'p/html/{id}.html'
        info = extract_html_information(file_path)
        insert_into_pgsql(id, info)
```

Comment: Offtopic: You are aware that this piece of code is vulnerable to SQL injection? Use placeholders for the input. SQL commands should not be constructed by merely appending strings.

Comment: @FrankHeikens Yes! This code is way different from the original one. I just tried to make things easier to understand.

Comment: The only way this is going to get faster is to run through the files, probably in batches, and create an in memory file that you then use to move the data into Postgres via either batch inserts or better yet [COPY](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-copy.html).